# Spinner NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, spinner

my problem is that my method **visListe()** will not work when add it to Spinner... it works when i add it to **onCreate**, but when added it to spinner it gave me error :

**LOGCAT**

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: no.hit.kvisli.heiverden, PID: 30934
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at no.hit.kvisli.heiverden.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:69)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**CODE**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
implements BasicDialogFragment.OnNameEnteredListener {
public static final String P1 = "melding";

private EditText input = null;
private Button listeKnapp = null;
private TextView visTekst = null;
double l;
double t;
double r;
double LB;
double AB;
int antTerminer;
Spinner spinner1;
private static final String[] VERDIER =
                          {"Serielån", "Annuitetslån"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //input        = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.skrivTekst);
    listeKnapp   = (Button) findViewById(R.id.liste_button);
    final EditText laan = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.laanInput);
    final EditText aar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.aarInput);
    final EditText termin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.terminInput);
    final EditText rente = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.renteInput);
    final Spinner valgSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    LB = Double.parseDouble(laan.getText().toString());
    l = Double.parseDouble(aar.getText().toString());
    t = Double.parseDouble(termin.getText().toString());
    r = Double.parseDouble(rente.getText().toString());

    AB = LB / (l*t) ;
    double RB = r/t;
    antTerminer = (int) (t*l);

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, VERDIER
    );
    valgSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);



    listeKnapp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Serielån")){
            visListe();
            }
            if(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Annuitetslån")){

            }
        }
    });




}

private String[] getListe(){
    String[] listeTabell = new String[antTerminer];
    for(int rad=0;rad<listeTabell.length;rad++) {
        double RB = Math.round(LB * (r / t) / 100);
        LB -= (int) AB;

        listeTabell[rad] = " Dette er termin nr : " + (rad + 1)  +
                            " Terminbeløp: " + ((int)(AB+RB)) +
                            " Avdrag: " + (int)AB +
                            " Rente: " + RB +
                            " Restgjeld: " + LB;


    }
    return listeTabell;
}
private void visListe() {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListeDemo.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putStringArray("no.hit.jon.liste", getListe());
    i.putExtra("no.hit.jon.listeBundle", b);
    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==0 && resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        String valgtTekst = data.getStringExtra("ValgtText");
        int pos = data.getIntExtra("ValgtPosisjon", -1);
        visTekst.setText("Du valgte linje " + pos + " : " + valgtTekst);
    }
}

private void startDialog() {
    BasicDialogFragment bdf = new BasicDialogFragment();
    bdf.show(getFragmentManager(), "basic");

}

public void OnFragmentInteractionListener(String nameEntered){
    visMinTekst();
}



private void visMinTekst() {
    visTekst.setText(input.getText());
    Toast melding = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            input.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    melding.show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

My code worked perfectly before spinner and i have used spinner by this way before without any problems, so im confused and not sure where to look for the problem.
PS. i want spinner to run my method **visListe()** to be more specific :)

Comment: You are using `R.id.spinner1` for `valgSpinner` and never do you initialize `spinner1`...

Answer (score 0):

where you `findViewById` for `spinner1` ?
you should change it by this `valgSpinner` I think.

```
if(valgSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Serielån")){
        visListe();
}
if(valgSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Annuitetslån")){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare `spinner1` here

```
Spinner spinner1;
```

but I never see you initialize it anywhere. You do, however, initialize another `Spinner` here

```
final Spinner valgSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

so you get a `NPE` in `onClick()` when you try to access `spinner1`. It looks like you have your variable names mixed up. Change it to

```
 listeKnapp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(valgSpinner .getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Serielån")){
        visListe();
        }
        if(valgSpinner .getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Annuitetslån")){

        }
    }
});
```

to use the variable you initialize and get rid of the useless variable `spinner1`.

Comment: thank you, it was stupid mistake ill try to be more aware next time :))

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the Issue is not the Spinner but rather the Array in Line 69 (as it sais), which gets "antTerminer" entries.

Comment: The stacktrace also says that it is in `onClick()` and not in `getListe()`